# Android Null Pointer Exception - Fragments (PA4AD)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I've been working my way through the book Professional Android 4 App dev, and have got stuck on one of the tutorials.  My app compiles fine but when I run it, it crashes with error NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object' on a  null object reference.  This occurs when I enter some text into the edittext and hit return.

The program appears to crash in the onNewItemAdded method, at the todoItems.add line.  As far as I can tell, my arraylist is initialized correctly.

I'm relativly new to Java as well as Android development and I'm stuck as to what is wrong.

For those not familiar with the book the app contains an edit text fragment and a list fragment.

Thanks for any help.

**ToDoListActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ToDoListActivity extends Activity
    implements NewItemFragment.OnNewItemAddedListener {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    private ArrayList<String> todoItems;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate your View
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get references to UI widgets
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        ToDoListFragment toDoListFragment =
                (ToDoListFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.ToDoListFragment);

        // Create the Array List of to do items
        final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Create the Array Adapter to bind the array to the List View
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                todoItems);

        // Bind the Array Adapter to the List View
        toDoListFragment.setListAdapter(aa);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void onNewItemAdded(String newItem) {
        System.out.println(newItem);
        todoItems.add(newItem);
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**NewItemFramgment.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link NewItemFragment.OnNewItemAddedListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 *
 */
public class NewItemFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnNewItemAddedListener onNewItemAddedListener;

    public interface OnNewItemAddedListener {
        public void onNewItemAdded(String newItem);
    }

    public NewItemFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_item_fragment, container, false);

        final EditText myEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

        myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) ||
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    String newItem = myEditText.getText().toString();
                    onNewItemAddedListener.onNewItemAdded(newItem);
                    myEditText.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return view;
}

/*    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            onNewItemAddedListener = (OnNewItemAddedListener)activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnItemAddedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        onNewItemAddedListener = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: @nem the error message in logcat is:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.todo.ToDoListActivity.onNewItemAdded(ToDoListActivity.java:63)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand your issue, you need to understand how [variable scopes](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) work in Java

In short, you have class variables (also called fields) and local variables:

```
class MyClass {
    int myVar;        // Class Variable - this variable is visible to the whole class

    void someMethod() {
        int myVar;    // Local Variable - this variable is visible only within someMethod()
    }
}
```

By using the same name for both class and local variables, the variable inside `someMethod()` is **"hidding"** the global class variable.

Therefore, your problem is that inside your `onCreate`, you are **re-declaring** an `ArrayList` called todoItems by saying:

```
// Create the Array List of to do items
final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This means that `todoItems` refers to this local version (only visible inside the `onCreate` method) and not the global version (visible for your whole class) you defined at the top of your class.

However, inside your `onNewItemAdded` method, the `todoItems` refers to the class global `ArrayList` which was never initialized (and is thus `null`) and that is why you get a `NullPointerException`.

You should change the statement above to:

```
todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So it refers to the class global `ArrayList`

**Note**: You have the same problem for your `ArrayAdapter<String> aa`